# Cannot create a constexpr array from a parameter pack inside a template

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, variadic-functions

I wanted to do a `static_assert` inside my `template` on an `array` created from a `parameter pack`.

Consider the following code:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
auto constexpr CreateArrConst(Args&&... args)
{
  std::array arr
  {
      args...
  };
  return arr;
}

template<typename... Args>
auto constexpr CreateArrConst_NotWorking(Args&&... args)
{
  constexpr std::array arr
  {
      args...
  };
  static_assert(arr.back() == 4);
  return arr;
}

int main() 
{
  static_assert(CreateArrConst(4).back() == 4);
  // uncomment this to reproduce compile error
  // static_assert(CreateArrConst_NotWorking(4).back() == 4);

  return 0;
}
```

The first template can create a `constexpr` which I can use at compile time to check inside main. However, once I try to create the same array (this time as `constexpr`) inside the template in `CreateArrConst_NotWorking` I get:

***error: ‘args#0’ is not a constant expression***

**Godbolt link to reproduce:** https://godbolt.org/z/YjGq76e5j

Does anyone know why I cannot create the constexpr inside the template?

Comment: @StackDanny Did you try to uncomment the 2nd function call in main?

Comment: `args` isn't a constant expression, maybe that's why.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that even though the template parameter pack named `Args` is a *constant expression* the function parameter pack named `args` isn't.

And since `args` isn't a constant expression it(`args...`) cannot be used as an initializer for the `constexpr` array in your given example.

---

To solve this you can replace `constexpr` with `const` for the `array`, as then the initializer is not required to be a constant expression.

```
template<typename... Args>
auto constexpr CreateArrConst_NotWorking(Args... args)
{
//vvvvv------------------->constexpr changed to const
  const std::array arr
  {
      args...
  };
  return arr;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8xPYhMM1Y)

Comment: True, but then I cannot do the static_assert inside the template!

Comment: Agreed, but your question is: *"Does anyone know why I cannot create the constexpr inside the template?"* for which my answer provides the explanation.

Comment: So, if args isn't constexpr, how can I create the constexpr arr in the first template (CreateArrConst)?

Comment: @SupAl Please ask a separate question for your follow-up question. I noticed that you edited your orignal question to include your follow up question. Please avoid doing that as it makes the existing answers obsolete. Feel free to ask as many separate questions as you want for your follow up questions. Like you can ask *"how can I create the constexpr arr in the first template"*. Both of your questions are interesting and needs to be separately answered.

Comment: makes sense. I'll follow that suggestion.

Comment: @SupAl Glad we agreed on the same.

Comment: Me too. I posed a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72473132/1454221
if you're interested in following up on the answer :)

Comment: Would it help if the function is declared `consteval` instead?

Comment: @Red.Wave I am doubtful of that. Though i am no expert on `consteval`(a C++20 feature). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473132/creating-a-constexpr-array-from-non-constexpr-argument) is the follow up question by OP.