# Creating a constexpr array from non-constexpr argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472543/cannot-create-a-constexpr-array-from-a-parameter-pack-inside-a-template/72472885#72472885) that `args` is not a *constant expression*. Now **my question is**: What should I modify in the given program so that I will be able to have an static_assert in the first variant without getting a compile time error.

In the following code:

```cpp
#include <array>

template<typename... Args>
auto constexpr CreateArrConst(Args&&... args)
{
  std::array arr
  {
      args...
  };
  //i want to have an static_assert here without error
  return arr;
}

template<typename... Args>
auto constexpr CreateArrConst_NotWorking(Args&&... args)
{
  constexpr std::array arr
  {
      args...
  };
  static_assert(arr.back() == 4);
  return arr;
}

int main() 
{
  static_assert(CreateArrConst(4).back() == 4);
  // uncomment this to reproduce compile error
  // static_assert(CreateArrConst_NotWorking(4).back() == 4);

  return 0;
}
```

Here's a link to reproduce:
https://godbolt.org/z/zjrP1Kvn7

Comment: The values of `args` are not compile-time constants. So when the function is compiled, there is no way for the compiler to check the static assertion. You could be calling the function with any arguments. If you need this, make the function parameters template parameters instead.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, this was already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72472885/12002570). This is a follow up question by OP.

Comment: @SupAl If you add `static_assert(arr.back() == 4);` inside the `CreateArrConst` then it won't work either. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zdacr81s3). The reason is the same as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72472885/12002570) and also by user17732522. I think you should phrase this follow up question a little differently so that it won't be the same as the original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472543/cannot-create-a-constexpr-array-from-a-parameter-pack-inside-a-template/72472885#72472885).

Comment: @AnoopRana, Hey again! That's exactly the issue with the first variant - that I cannot do the static_assert, so that's why I tried to make the array constexpr, but to no avail. What I do not understand is the following: 
1) In the first case, at compile time it can create a constexpr array that can be returned and checked in the main function.
2) If I try to do the constexpr before returning it, it's not possible.

So how can it instantiate the constexpr in the first place if the arguments are not constexpr?

Comment: @SupAl Ok, then in this question you should ask: *"What should i modify in the given program so that i will be able to have an static_assert in the first variant"*. This will make this question much clear and different from the last question IMO.

Comment: @AnoopRana, Great suggestion! Should I make another new stack overflow question for this, you think?

Comment: @SupAl No, you can just add it in this question only. Here there is no need to ask a separate question as nobody has answered it. I am thinking maybe i can edit this question.

Comment: @SupAl I have modified your question to make it more clear, can you see and confirm if it matches your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the arguments into template parameters. Unfortunately it then can't deduce the type of the arguments anymore:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T, T... args>
auto constexpr CreateArrConst()
{
  constexpr std::array arr
  {
      args...
  };
  static_assert(arr.back() == 4);
  return arr;
}

// cleaner solution requiring C++17
template<auto... args>
auto constexpr CreateArrConstCpp17()
{
  constexpr std::array arr
  {
      args...
  };
  static_assert(arr.back() == 4);
  return arr;
}

int main() 
{
  static_assert(CreateArrConst<int, 4>().back() == 4);            // <-- Works!

  static_assert(CreateArrConstCpp17<1, 2, 3, 4>().back() == 4);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since C++17 `auto` as type will work with deduction.

Comment: Is `auto...` the same as `T...`? Meaning all the same type? Although I guess it will just fail to create the array if the types don't match.

Comment: No, it doesn't enforce equal types, but neither does OP's function template. However, the CTAD for `std::array` will fail if the types are not all equal in either case.

Comment: This works great. An even more clean solution (requiring C++17) is to do as suggested by @user17732522 and just write `template<auto... args>`. In that case the parameters can be auto deduced.