# Static constexpr member function not returning a constexpr value when calling it inside the constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, variadic-templates, constexpr

I have a template class which has a variadic constructor that takes specializations of itself. It looks like that (basically):

```
template<std::size_t SIZE_>
class SomeClass {
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t SIZE = SIZE_;

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr std::size_t computeTotalSize(const T& t) {
        return T::SIZE;
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    static constexpr std::size_t computeTotalSize(const T& t, const Ts&... ts) {
        return computeTotalSize(t) + computeTotalSize(ts...);
    }

    SomeClass() = default;

    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    SomeClass(const T& t, const Ts&... ts) {
        static_assert(computeTotalSize(t, ts...) == SOME_NUMBER, "SOME_MESSAGE");
        // some other stuff
    }
};
```

Now I try to instantiate `SomeClass<SOME_NUMBER>`:

```
SomeClass<SOME_NUMBER> someObject((SomeClass<1>()), (SomeClass<2>()), (SomeClass<3>()));
```

I get the following errors:

```
error: constexpr variable 'totalSize' must be initialized by a constant expression
note: function parameter 't' with unknown value cannot be used in a constant expression
```

I expected this to work fine since I have declared `computeTotalSize` function as `constexpr` and the type of all parameters is known at compile time.

I found out that if I call `computeTotalSize` function directly, it works fine. For example, the following compiles:

```
constexpr std::size_t totalSize = SomeClass<SOME_NUMBER>::computeTotalSize((SomeClass<1>()), (SomeClass<2>()), (SomeClass<3>()));
```

Why is it returning a constexpr in the second case only? How can I make it work in the constructor?

Comment: the constructor is not constexpr

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473132/creating-a-constexpr-array-from-non-constexpr-argument/72478402

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that even though the template parameter named `T` is a *constant expression* the function parameter named `t` isn't.

And since `t` isn't a constant expression it cannot be used in the constexpr context you're trying to use it in as mentioned in the error saying:

```
function parameter 't' with unknown value cannot be used in a constant expression
```